# Why do I get a error in leetcode submission but pass in IDE using the same code?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am solving LeetCode question: [234. Palindrome Linked List](https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-linked-list/):

> Given the `head` of a singly linked list, return `true` if it is a palindrome.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> [image]
>
> ```
> Input: head = [1,2,2,1]
> Output: true
> ```
>
> #### Example 2:
>
> [image]
>
> ```
> Input: head = [1,2]
> Output: false
> ```
>
> #### Constraints:
>
> - The number of nodes in the list is in the range `[1, 10⁵]`.
> - `0 <= Node.val <= 9`
>
> **Follow up:** Could you do it in `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space?

Using C++ I get the error below:

```
=================================================================
==42==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x602000000098 at pc 0x00000037ac7d bp 0x7ffc1760fda0 sp 0x7ffc1760fd98
READ of size 8 at 0x602000000098 thread T0
    #2 0x7f5a8c3e70b2  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
0x602000000098 is located 8 bytes inside of 16-byte region [0x602000000090,0x6020000000a0)
freed by thread T0 here:
    #3 0x7f5a8c3e70b2  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
previously allocated by thread T0 here:......
```

Here is my code:

```
/*code only in VS 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
  struct ListNode {
     int val;
      ListNode *next;
      ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
      ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
      ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
  };*/
 
class Solution {
public:

    bool isPalindrome(ListNode* head) {
        if (!head->next) {
            return true;
        }
        ListNode* slow = head;
        ListNode* fast = head;
        while (fast && fast->next) {
            fast = fast->next->next;
            slow = slow->next;
        }
        ListNode* prev = slow;
        ListNode* current = prev->next;
        while (current) {
            ListNode* temp = current->next;
            current->next = prev;
            prev = current;
            current = temp;
        }
        while (head != slow)
        {
            if (head->val != prev->val) {
                return false;
            }
            head = head->next;
            prev = prev->next;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
/*code only in VS 
int main()
{
    ListNode* a = new ListNode(1);
    ListNode* b = new ListNode(0);
    ListNode* c = new ListNode(3);
    ListNode* d = new ListNode(4);   //[1,0,3,4,0,1]
    ListNode* e = new ListNode(0);
    ListNode* f = new ListNode(1);
    a->next = b;
    b->next = c;
    c->next = d;
    d->next = e;
    e->next = f;
    Solution solution;
    cout << solution.isPalindrome(a);

}*/
```

I can run it and get the right answer in my IDE (Visual Studio 2019 Community), but get an error in the LeetCode submission.

Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: That message reads like a pointer problem. Have you tested other test-cases than the one published on the so-called "competition" site? How about corner-cases like null pointer input? Have you tried to step through the code using a debugger (while monitoring variables *and* drawing the operations using pen and paper) to see that your code really does what you intended it to do?

Comment: That's undefined behavior for you, the fact that a program seems to run doesn't mean it is correct. Your code does have a bug: accessing memory that was previously deleted. As long as that memory is not overwritten you may still get the expected results, but it is by no means guaranteed. The leet-code compiler just does a better job at detecting that you do this and will give you the error.

Comment: Why is `isPalindrome()` modifying the list in the 2nd `while` loop? Checking for a Palindrome should be a read-only operation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau cuz this question requires O(1) space complexity in follow up and reversing half of the list seems a good choice.

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Questions needs to be *self-contained*. All information should be in the question itself, not as external links (which can change, go stale or disappear).

Comment: You should probably make your code more like what the checker is going to do, e.g. delete the list after the test, check lists that have both odd and even length etc.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I tested edge cases like length 1 and both even and odd cases,it seems ok in IDE so I really don't know what's going on..In leetcode I can't pass a single test case.

Comment: Have you tried iterating through the list and deleting nodes like the test probably does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs when the Leet Code test system will try to release the memory used by the previous test case, before launching the next one.

Your code leaves the list in a state where it will run in cycles: the node that follows `slow` has been rewired by your code to point back to `slow`.

We can imagine how the Leet Code clean-up code will free the node that `slow` refers to, then free the next node's memory, and then arrive again at `slow` which was already freed/deleted. This is the cause of this error. It is therefore important that you leave the list in a consistent state, where it has the original number of nodes, and there are no cycles.

To resolve the error quicly, just add this line before the last loop:

```
slow->next = nullptr;
```

However, this leaves the second (reversed) half of your list unreachable for  Leet Code to clean up. That's not really fair (although fast). To do it properly, make `slow` stop at the left side of the center when the list size is even (by moving `fast` one step ahead), and then rewire the tail of the first half with the (new) head of the second half (which was reversed):

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool isPalindrome(ListNode* head) {
        if (!head->next) {
            return true;
        }
        ListNode* slow = head;
        ListNode* fast = head->next; // Stop loop sooner when size is even
        while (fast && fast->next) {
            fast = fast->next->next;
            slow = slow->next;
        }
        ListNode* prev = nullptr; // this will be assigned to the new tail
        ListNode* current = slow->next;
        while (current) {
            ListNode* temp = current->next;
            current->next = prev;
            prev = current;
            current = temp;
        }
        slow->next = prev; // link tail of first half to head of reversed part
        while (prev) // Continue the walk in second half until the list's end
        {
            if (head->val != prev->val) {
                return false;
            }
            head = head->next;
            prev = prev->next;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: test cases 85 / 85 passed.Thanks alot,having been stuck in this problem for a day and didn't know this whole test system implementation before.you really saved my day!

Comment: NB: I improved my answer.